What is the best way to fan-out this BGA?
I am working on a hobby project, trying to make a board with a STM32MP1. As a challenge I want to make it the cheapest possible with JLCPCB PCB assembly, and so I took the single core BGA-257 version, with a pitch of 0.5mm, and a bunch of basic components.
I want to use a 6-layer board, which gives free via-in-pad for small boards, which would be helpful to fan-out a few signals, still I could not find how to use them without additional costs.
With the manufacturer limits of 3 mils/0.07 6mm for tracks, pads diameter of 0.25 mm (0.23 mm recommended by ST), clearance from pad of 0.09 mm, I cannot pass the outer pads :

If I cheat and set the pad diameter to 0.24 mm, it can go through, but there is a risk manufacturer will refuse the PCB, or the PCB would have 0.25 mm diameter anyway with risks of failure:

Now, comes via-in-pad.
Vias with the manufacturer are free of additional charges for a hole of 0.2 mm and ring of 0.45 mm, or hole of 0.3 mm and ring of 0.4 mm
If I use them it seems fine with clearance requirements:


Unfortunately, I guess the pad will be the size of the ring, and 0.4mm or 0.45 mm is clearly off-limits and could result in bad connection with the balls, I could not find a way to decrease pad size even with solder mask, is there any solution?
JLCPCB recommends to set ring size to 0.25 mm and hole 0.15, but this dramatically increases the cost of the board.
Finally, last solution I found would be to change the form of the BGA pads on the outer limit, I did this for an eMMC chip some time ago and it worked perfectly, then I can push tracks between pads:

Is this solution viable for a SoC or am I out of luck?

The packages with 0.8mm pitch are more expensive, but you might not have cost adders on the PCB side with recommended sizes/clearances etc. Have you compared the overall cost?

"pads diameter of 25 mm" Do you mean 0.25 mm?

@Mat Unfortunately, they don't have much available in 0.8mm, 20 parts available for the 448.
winny : Yes sorry, I corrected.
